# How to adjust floyd rose tilting forward?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, bridge, tremolo

I have been changing strings recently on my electric guitar, which has a Floyd Rose licensed bridge. I had strings on it (dont know which kind) and changed them to SL Alice strings  (0.009 etc.). But while replacing the strings, the floyd rose is tilting way too much forward.

[image]
Now I have trouble to fix this problem and want to know what to do.  I tried to tighten the height post screws on top of the bridge. I also try to tighten the wood screws on the back of the guitar to increase the spring tension. And I also changed the spring position to try to increase the spring tension from this:

[image: springs]

But still, as I try to tune the guitar, the bridge is still tilting way too much forward:
[image]

I read online about how to set up the floyd rose bridge, but it seems that I have tried everything and the bridge is always tilting forward...  What should I do ?     Add more springs?  Change to strings with higher gauge?

Comment: Put on more springs, I had the same prob and I had a spring with me which they gave extra when I bought my strat.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I think I will then add a spring or two... as you suggest.   Anyone, any other suggestions?

Comment: I added just one and it worked for me. Keep the configuration symmetric, This happens when you move to a string gauge higher than the guitar originally had, I went up by a whole lot when it happened to me, but one spring sufficed for me back then.

Comment: That is good to know. I will order some springs soon to try it, and add just one first and keep it symetric. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting more springs is one solution, but by far the simplest thing with the type of trem you have is just to tighten those two screws in the back, pulling the claw further forwards. In combination with the angled springs you should be able to pull the tension up a lot, bringing the trem body down towards the body.

Comment: If you look at OPs pictures, there isn't a lot of thread left on the screws to pull the claw back suggesting someone has already tried that at some stage. Based on experience I can almost certainly tell you it wont be enough to correct the problem.

Comment: Based on my experience, doing this for 40-ish years, I reckon the combination of tightening them and adding two more springs will easily be enough. Those screws make a hell of a difference.

Comment: Yes, adding either adding extra, or replacing the springs will fix the problem. Pushing the screws in that extra 5mm on its own (as you answers suggests as being the 'simplest thing') wont!

Answer (score 2):

The tension springs in the back do wear out over time and lose power. Either get a whole new set, or get extras and add more in.

Changing strings to a higher gauge will make the problem worse.

You can also get devices like a [Tremol-No](https://www.tremol-no.com/) that will set and lock the Floyd Rose in place. It removes the ability to do dive bombs with your whammy bar, but makes sure your Floyd Rose will always be dead level while retaining the ability to use the locking nut and fine tuners.